# Local file not readable when trying to upload in Swift

Tags: swift, sftp

I'm using DLFTPClient for sftp upload. This is my code.

```
var connection: DLSFTPConnection = DLSFTPConnection(hostname: "192.168.1.1", port: 2222, username: "test", password: "test")
var remoteBasePath = "/test"
var localPath: String = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: ".jpg")?.absoluteString
var request: DLSFTPRequest?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var successBlock = {() -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
            // login successful
            print("loginSuccess")
        })
        } as? DLSFTPClientSuccessBlock

    var failureBlock = {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

            print(error)
        })
        print("error")
        } as? DLSFTPClientFailureBlock
    connection.connect(successBlock: successBlock, failureBlock: failureBlock)
}


@IBAction func startTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("sending")

    var successBlock = {(_ file: DLSFTPFile, _ startTime: Date, _ finishTime: Date) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

            var alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Upload completed", message: "", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "")
            alertView.show()
        })
        print("success")
        } as? DLSFTPClientFileTransferSuccessBlock

    var failureBlock = {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

            print(error)
        })
        print("error")
        } as? DLSFTPClientFailureBlock

    var localFilename = "test.jpg"
    var remotePath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: remoteBasePath).appendingPathComponent(localFilename).absoluteString
    request = DLSFTPUploadRequest(remotePath: remotePath, localPath: localPath, successBlock: successBlock, failureBlock: failureBlock, progressBlock: nil)
    connection.submitRequest(request)

}
```

Everything seems to be doing fine when I try to login, it returns success. But when I try to upload the file it returns error: (Error Domain=SFTPClientErrorDomain Code=29 "Local file is not readable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Local file is not readable})

Is there something wrong with my remote base path and local path? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `remotePath` is a url string with the `file://` scheme. I doubt this is intended.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using .path instead of .absoluteString in localPath and remotePath.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! It also solved my problem when sharing an attachment using UIActivityViewController and Email, which gave me Attachments Error confirming URL is readable errors in console. Just typing this all here for future people having the same problem. ;)